# What to share in a research grant/fellowship application

Tags: research-process

My question - Is it safe to add the phd  dissertations topic including problem statement and objectives in research proposal in a research grant .Or do we need to add only a portion of it.

Comment: I'm not clear what it is you're asking: "safe" for whom? what is the danger/concern?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The two concerns, requiring balance, are that you need to convince reviewers that you are the right person for the grant but that you also probably have a length limit (even if informal) to the application.

The bulk of the application should be on the work to be done, not past work, but if saying more than the minimum about your qualifications is helpful then you can do that.

If the analysis of your likely success in the application requires you to go into some detail about your insights in the problem area, then that would be appropriate. But keep the focus on the future.

As in most things, don't bore your reader.